# Can I store jsp tag return value in a variable without it being coerced to a string?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

```
<c:set var="userProfile"><sec:authentication property="principal" /></c:set>
```

I've got a legacy security system which I'm porting over to spring security. In this case I want to simply store the user principal in a variable which is what all the legacy code expects.

As it stands the variable userProfile contains principal.toString().

This is probably best moved to the controller anyway but out of interest is there an easy way to achieve this in the jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with setting a value with `<c:set>` inside the body is that it's always a string (evaluation of the body content as string). If using the `value` attribute the result is of the type of the evaluated value:

```
<c:set var="userProfile" value="${...}" />
```

But the above is possible only if you have something "exposed" to evaluate.

I'm assuming that the `<sec:authentication>` tag is part of [Spring Security's taglibs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/taglibs/authz/AuthenticationTag.html)? If that's the case, the way you are using it is causing the string coercion (not the `<c:set>`).

The tag can either write the property value to the output stream (as a string) or "expose" the property as a variable. In the latter case, this should do what you need:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal" var="userProfile" />
```